# Why can't I output the name of the row that corresponds to this index in the dataset

Tags: r

```
summary(college$Grad.Rate)
min.GradRate = college[college$Grad.Rate == 10, ]
nrow(min.GradRate)

[1] 1

rownames[as.numeric(rownames(min.GradRate))]
  Error in rownames[as.numeric(rownames(min.GradRate))] : 
    object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

I don't know any other way to output the row name and I don't know how to fix this error.

Comment: `rownames()` is a function not a `data.frame` The outermost `rownames` in the last line should be followed by round brackets rather than rectangular brackets.

Comment: please provide a reproducible example. Use `dput(head(college))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```r
library(ISLR)

min.GradRate = College[College$Grad.Rate == 10,]
row.names(min.GradRate)
```

Output is:

```
[1] "Texas Southern University"
```